# $Ref flag reappears even after deletion

Tags: xpages

We have an Xpage based Web mail-in application. Some emails are coming with $Ref field (response document). We wanted to convert them into normal document by removing $Ref field so that it will no longer a response one. We are able to delete the $ref field but it reappears again after saving the documents from web interface(xpage) and it makes all such documents again response document. This started happening recently and working well earlier. Can you please suggest what is the root cause? How to stop it?

```
Sub Initialize
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim coll As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim count As Long

    Set db = s.Currentdatabase
    Set coll = db.Unprocesseddocuments
    MessageBox "Count : " & coll.Count
    'Exit Sub
    count = 1
    Set doc = coll.Getfirstdocument()

    While Not doc Is Nothing
        If doc.Hasitem("$Ref") Then
            Call doc.Removeitem("$Ref")
            Call doc.Save(false, false)
        End If
        Print count
        count = count + 1
        Set doc = coll.Getnextdocument(doc)
    Wend
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MessageBox "Error " & Error & " at line " & Erl
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add the code that you used to "convert them into normal document".  This will help in troubleshooting your issue.

Comment: While Not doc Is Nothing
  If doc.Hasitem("$Ref") Then
   Call doc.Removeitem("$Ref")
   Call doc.Save(false, false)
  End If
  Print count
  count = count + 1
  Set doc = coll.Getnextdocument(doc)
 Wend

Comment: Incredibly minor quibble: count should be an integer. This has no effect on the code execution, but is a better practice.

Comment: So, if it worked earlier, what changed in your system that made it stop working?

Comment: we have some design change and signed the xpage too; but I have no clue what can be reason behind this. So asking, it looks like some bug in software level. I want workaround.

Comment: Give more info. Did you open/edit the doc in XP before the code runs? Is that agent triggered by XP? Does XP data source specify "Make response" properties? And so on...

Comment: The keyword for me is "signed" - are you sure you can save the document? Maybe it's a rights issue. Are changes saved to the document?

Comment: of course; saving from Xpage happening very well. But $Ref again comes back with old reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your save method to `Call doc.Save(true, false)`.

This will force the document save, and also prevent creating a response.

Also verify that you are running the agent on a server not accessable to active users. Also verify that you are only running your agent once, and that it isn't enabled on multible replicas.

---

Have you tried using `If(doc.isResponse) Then` instead of `If doc.Hasitem("$Ref") Then`

*Note: I am looking in the java editor, but assume that the isResponse method is also in LS.*

Comment: We did all such possibilities and no clue.

Comment: @SubhasishMukhopadhyay, added another suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Again it does not make any value & sense; because my code is able to remove successfully $Ref successfully, I saw from property. But I am really struggling to understand from where $Ref is regenerated with old value after saving from Xpage.

Comment: How are you launching this process?  I think it should be an agent, and not run from an XPage.  XPages is probably saving the old value in memory.  Please include XSP code in your question, if you launch it there.

Comment: What XSP code you are asking for? This is to submit a big form data and has with lot of fields, csjs, ssjs etc. Event the $Ref will reappear if I save after 5 days also.

Comment: Post code that kicks off the code above.  Because it is LS, I assume that it is an agent.  Post the code that kicks off the agent.

Comment: This agent I am running manually for some documents as support activities. Please notice the code; it works on selected documents.

Comment: If you 1) Open XPage with fields bound to document 2) Run Agent that removes $Ref (with doc.save(false, false) 3) Save fields on XPage bound to document.  I think that your changes in the agent will be overwritten, which is your problem.  *Please keep in mind, that all I have to go on is what you have already shared.*

Comment: If this is so simple then I would not post this in the forum. :-) smile; I know that if I run and fix the document then I should refresh it from web too.I would be more than happy if someone from product development team would jump and help me answering.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it was an easy issue, just that to take into consideration that my answer is only based on what you shared. Perhaps in the future, list all the things you already tried in your question.  Best of luck getting it fixed.

Comment: @SubhasishMukhopadhyay You don't need someone from the product development team. If you don't provide more information, they won't be able to help you either.

Answer (score 0):

Wheather a document is a response is controlled by a property of the used form. As long as you do not assign another form that is a "Document" and not a "Response", you will most probably not be able to remove the "isresponse"- flag. As already told: most probably your xpage saves the "frontend" document after your backend manipulation and resets the state (form validation enabled in xpage properties). But without source code of the xpage one cannot tell.

Answer (score 0):

Check the form name. Emails can use either the "Memo" form or the "Reply" form. Emails using the Reply form are response documents. You may also need to change the form to "Memo".

Comment: Not this case. We tried to remove  $Ref flag keeping session.ConverMime = False in PostQueueSave event agent in XPage. Now when we are doing the same keeping session.ConverMime = True and it is working fine.